# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str' How to solve it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to get in numbers how many processes with the same name "chrome.exe" are running.

This is my python script

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()

for process in c.Win32_Process ():
    #print (process.Name)
    if process.Name == "chrome.exe" & process.Name > 1:
        print (process.Name)
```

when I run this script I get something like this:

```
chrome.exe
chrome.exe
chrome.exe
chrome.exe
chrome.exe
chrome.exe
chrome.exe
chrome.exe
```

but I need to get the quantity in numbers and if it is greater than 1 print something and also get this error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: You probably want the `and` operator instead of the bitwise `&` operator.

Comment: If you need to count the processes, create a counter variable and increment it by 1 inside your loop.

Comment: I'm unclear though what you're trying to do with `> 1`. You have just checked that the `.Name` equals a certain string, and next you're checking whether it's greater than 1…?!

Comment: @deceze 
I know it's a mistake, for that reason I suggest some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh boy it's a little messy here.
For question: You need to change '`&`' to '`and`'

others:

`for process in c.Win32_Process ():` -> `for process in c.Win32_Process():`

`print (process.Name)` -> `print(process.Name)`

finally:

```
i = 1 # or 0, do as you need
for process in c.Win32_Process():
    if process.Name == "chrome.exe" and i > 1:
        print(process.Name)
    i += 1 # there are more elegenat ways to do this, but let's keep this simple
```